# Calculation of power of survival study

Tags: survival, median, statistical-power

For an upcoming study of about 200 (rare) cancer cases, we would like to determine the power of detection for a hypothetical marker, present in 10% of cases, i.e. 20 cases with a hazard ratio of 3.0. Cases will be followed up for at least 5 years. We will have the option to validate any identified markers in an independent additional 200 member cohort.

In the past, I have used the program [PS](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/twiki/bin/view/Main/PowerSampleSize) to run power calculations, which is fairly idiot-proof for a biologist like me. However, the cancer we are studying tends to have an overall survival rate of 60%, so the calculation of a median survival time doesn't really make sense (at least to me).

What I wanted to know is whether there are approaches available for the calculation of power which can overcome this limitation, and if so, how can I easily implement them in, ideally, R.

I have googled around to find an answer, but haven't met with success so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the R Hmisc package see the cpower and spower functions.  spower does simulations for complex situations (late treatment effect, drop-in, drop-out, etc.) whereas cpower using normal approximations for simpler cases such as yours.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledgeable comment. I will explore the cpower function.

Comment: @Frank Harrel - is there a step-by-step tutorial that you are aware of on using ```cpower()```. I have found the user manual, but would like to see multiple scenarios. For example, I would like to see how many patients I need to achieve different significance. So, make a plot of alpha vs sample size, at a constant power. I am not sure how to go about this! I have preliminary data on a small group of subjects with a very large effect.

Comment: There's just the examples in the help file.  Note that "significance" has come to mean almost nothing.